# how to debug my own go module from another project

Tags: debugging, go, module

Curious as to how to run & debug changes to a private module I have authorship over from a dependent project?

If I have MyApp.go in its own project which `import "github.com/my-co/my-mod/a-package"` and I want to make changes to a-package in my-mod and run MyApp.go in order to exercise the changes I'm making to a-package - how can I set things up so that Go uses the live version I am editing locally?

Ideally, I'd be able to step through calling side functions into the source already on my system for that module & package - where I can then edit the source directly.

I can definitely push changes to my-mod, and then version them at github, and then force my local project to use the latest version of my-mod.  But that's a huge round-trip that makes minor edits and fixes cumbersome - and requires a new minor version for every single one.

That sounds very inefficient - surely there's a better way?

Comment: Use a `replace` directive in `go.mod` to point a module reference at a local path as outlined here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that your copy of `my-mod` is in `/home/foo/my-mod`, and your copy of `MyApp.go` is in a module rooted at `/home/foo/some-app`, then if you want to work on `MyApp.go`, you should update `/home/foo/some-app/go.mod` to include the line:

```
replace github.com/my-co/my-mod => /some/filesystem/path/my-mod
```

If you instead want to work in the directory containing `a-package`, you can set up a similar `replace` directive in `/home/foo/my-mod/go.mod` .

Comment: Adrian really answered me above - but for visibility for others coming to find the answer - I appreciate you spelling it out.  Thanks.